# Discord.Net using Bots avatar as IconURL/AvatarURL

Tags: c#, vb.net, discord, discord.net

I am currently an embed and what I'm having trouble is getting the bot's avatar as the icon. This is in Visual Basic but if there's something in C# I could work with that and try to get it to work.

```
        Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
        .Title = "Help comand",
        .Description = "hello",
        .Color = New Color(255, 0, 0),
        .ThumbnailUrl = Context.Guild.IconUrl,
        .Timestamp = Context.Message.Timestamp,
        .Footer = New EmbedFooterBuilder With {
                .Text = "Footer",
                .IconUrl = "URL COMMAND HERE"
            }
        }
```

How would I get around doing this? I've been seeing this in other languages but to my findings none on Discord.Net

Comment: It's pretty much the same way you get the guild icon url, there is a `GatAvatarUrl` on `User` objects... so in this case `Context.CurrentUser` would be the bot user.

Comment: @Anu6is thanks! Wasn't exactly Context.CurrentUser.GetAvatarUrl but you lead down the right track. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//as an author
var builder = new EmbedBuilder()
                .WithAuthor(author =>
                {
                    author
                    .WithIconUrl(Context.User.GetAvatarUrl() ?? Context.User.GetDefaultAvatarUrl());
                });
            var embed = builder.Build();

            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(null, false, embed);
```

```
//as a title
var builder = new EmbedBuilder()
                .WithTitle(Context.User.GetAvatarUrl() ?? Context.User.GetDefaultAvatarUrl());
            var embed = builder.Build();

            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(null, false, embed);
```

And so on, you can use it almost everywhere. I am kinda late but doing it for the new people who search this